# iOS EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) crash on iOS 9 only

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making a app work with other team, the other team deploy a framework to me.
And I import those framework to my app.

And I try to build with my testing devices , they are iPhone 8 Plus(iOS 11), iPhone 7 Plus(iOS 10), two iPhone X (iOS 11) , iPhone Pro (iOS 11) above device also work fine.

But not work with iPhone 5c (iOS 9.3) iPad Mini 1 (iOS 9.3) . They only work with first time build with Xcode only , after disconnect the cable , open the app second time ,it always crash after the launch image.

Code in appdelegate.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) FrameworkViewController *InfoVC;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyNavigationViewController *conNav;
```

Init code in my appdelegate.m

```
NSBundle *myframeworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[FrameworkManager class]];
InfoVC = [[FrameworkViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FrameworkViewController" bundle:myframeworkBundle];
conNav = [[MyNavigationViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:InfoVC];
InfoVC.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                                initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"leftMenu_icon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                target:self
                                                action:@selector(myfunction:)];
conNav.tabBarItem.title=@"TAP_Information";
conNav.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_info.png"];
```

I add a breakpoint and got InfoVC return nil with those iPhone 5c and Mini 1.
But those works device will show a address. And I think the infoVC is nil and I try to set the leftbarButtonItem to a nil object to cause the crash , but how to fix this? I try to add a main_queue seem not work .

-------------Update-------------

I try to add some NSLog to see those nil object , and I found that NSlog can print out a valid address , the nil is cause by the app is crashed.
Now it crashed randomly at iOS 9 device only . All the crash are EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0).

[Device error log1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orcx1.png)
[Device error log2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A2P7.png)

Comment: why you are setting nil in here in app delegate ???? You should customise nav bar in respected controller ....if I am not wrong this must be the issue for IOS version 9 or below because these devices run lower version of IOS

Comment: I think the problem is the InfoVC run init code also become a nil object . I can take away the nav bar setting , but the InfoVC is part of the tabbar controller , adding a nil object to the controllers will also crash. So the root cause should solve the infoVC return nil problem .

Comment: yeah, maybe you are right, have tested both iPhones X and 5s with same code ? and one works but other not ?

Comment: Yes , same code with iPhone 5 and iPad Mini showing nil and the others showing the address (init success)

Comment: that's really weird, let me check it out once again

Comment: @Jam Have you checked whether `myFrameworkBundle` returns a value?

Comment: @RhuariGlen Yes , I added a break point and the "myFrameworkBundle" showing a valid address

Comment: @Jam and is it a `.framework` or `.a` you have been provided?

Comment: @RhuariGlen it is a .framework

Answer (score 1):

If you have been provided a `.framework` file, I would recommend searching for your NSBundle using one of the following function:

`+ (NSBundle *)bundleWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier`

`+ (instancetype)bundleWithPath:(NSString *)path`

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle/1411929-bundlewithidentifier?language=objc):

> This method is typically used by frameworks and plug-ins to locate their own bundle at runtime. This method may be somewhat more efficient than trying to locate the bundle using the bundleForClass: method. However, if the initial lookup of an already loaded and cached bundle with the specified identifier fails, this method uses potentially time-consuming heuristics to attempt to locate the bundle. As an optimization, you can use the bundleWithPath: or bundleWithURL: method instead to avoid file system traversal.